# Add External User using Custom API

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server

I want to add external users in SharePoint 2013 site using custom build API. this API will be consumed by our 3rd party application. any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Able to do this. 
Once you configure a FBA on site. write csom to access a site. while creating a client context please add below code.

```
using (clientContext = new ClientContext(<site URL>))
            {
                clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest += new EventHandler<WebRequestEventArgs>(clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest);
                clientContext.Load(clientContext.Web, web => web.Title);
                clientContext.ExecuteQuery();}
static void clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest(object sender, WebRequestEventArgs e)
    {
        e.WebRequestExecutor.WebRequest.Headers.Add("X-FORMS_BASED_AUTH_ACCEPTED", "f");
    }
```

it will create context for FBA site and you are able to access the site context.